# Running other jobs form jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I can't install Multijob project plugin due to security restrictions and I have a need to orchestrate multiple jobs running in this order:

1. one job
2. two parallel jobs
3. one job
4. one job

they are dependendent and should be run in that exact order.
I try to do something like this

```
def multiJob(??? jobs, ??? parameters) {
  def branches = [:]    
  for (int i = 0; i < jobs.length; i++) {
     def index = i
     branches["branch${i}"] = {
       build job: "$jobs[index]", parameters: $paramaters[index] 
     }
  }
  parallel branches
}
//...
pipeline {
  //..
  stages{
    stage ('first job') {
      multijob(['firstJob'], [paramsJob1])
    }
    stage ('second job') {
      multijob(['parallel1', 'paralel2'], [paramsParallel1, paramsParallel2])
    }
   //...
  }
}
```

problem is that I'm not familiar with groovy and jenkins pipeline so I don't know 
what type should variables **jobs** and **parameters** of method **multiJob** be and how to properly call **multiJob** from pipeline step

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
   pipeline {
        agent none
        stages {
            stage('Build job 1'){
                build 'Job1' // name of job1
            }
            stage('Run Parallel Builds') {
                parallel {
                    stage('Build job2') {

                        build 'Job2' // name of job2

                    }
                    stage('Build job3') {
                        build 'Job3' // name of job3
                    }
                }
                stage('Build job 4'){
                    build 'Job4' // name of job4
                }
                stage('Build job 5'){
                    build 'Job5' // name of job5
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

For a better/detalied understanding you can refer here https://jenkins.io/blog/2017/09/25/declarative-1/

Hope it helps :)